# How to handle jquery repeater html in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jquery-plugins

> this is my .cshtml page code,i use jquery repeater is in this code repeater is working fine but i want to add some modification in this repeater but i am stuck here. you can see my code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "repeater" }))
{
    <div data-repeater-list="">
        <div data-repeater-item="">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <input type="file" name="Docfiles" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add" />
    <button>Save</button>
}
@section Scripts{
    <!-- Import repeater js  -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.repeater/1.2.1/jquery.repeater.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.repeater').repeater({
                // (Optional)
                // start with an empty list of repeaters. Set your first (and only)
                // "data-repeater-item" with style="display:none;" and pass the
                // following configuration flag
                initEmpty: true,

                // (Optional)
                // "show" is called just after an item is added.  The item is hidden
                // at this point.  If a show callback is not given the item will
                // have $(this).show() called on it.
                show: function () {
                    $(this).slideDown();
                },
                // (Optional)
                // "hide" is called when a user clicks on a data-repeater-delete
                // element.  The item is still visible.  "hide" is passed a function
                // as its first argument which will properly remove the item.
                // "hide" allows for a confirmation step, to send a delete request
                // to the server, etc.  If a hide callback is not given the item
                // will be deleted.
                hide: function (deleteElement) {
                    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
                        $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
                    }
                },

                // (Optional)
                // Removes the delete button from the first list item,
                // defaults to false.
                isFirstItemUndeletable: true
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

> i want to change html in this formate like this as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,the name format is set in jquery.repeater.js,if you want to change it,you need to change jquery.repeater.js,here is a demo worked:

1.Add the [jquery.repeater.js](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater/blob/master/jquery.repeater.js) to your project.

I copy the js to my project like this:

[image]

2.Find `setIndexes` in the jquery and change `var newName = groupName + '[' + index + '][' + name + ']' +`like this(You can also change it to other format you want):
[image]

3.change your script src from cdnjs to your own project:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-repeater/jquery.repeater.js"></script>
```

4.Result:
[image]