# ASP.NET Core Model Binding using jquery repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, model-binding, jquery.repeater

There are many similar question yet I don't find any suitable answers.

I use Jquery repeater [repeater](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater) and repeater is working fine but I can not bind my model as input name doesn't match my model name.

So I followed this answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63924939/how-to-handle-jquery-repeater-html-in-mvc) and changed the input name group-a[0][text-input] to group-a[0].text-input
which works perfectly fine for the first input but as soon as I add next row input name becomes group-a[0].0

Now again I can't bind my model.

I want to ask how to solve this issue or please suggest me any better approach to bind the model.
I've been searching for some days but still didn't get the answer and I'm also a beginner.
Thank you

```
enter code here public class CreatePurchaseOrderModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Vendor name is required")]
    public string VendorId { get; set; }

    public List<ProductDetails> ProductDetails { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal VatAmount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal NetAmount { get; set; }
    public bool IsVatType { get; set; }
    public List<VendorModel>? Vendor { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDetails
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product name is required")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity  is required")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Rate  is required")]
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
}


enter code here public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePurchaseOrder(CreatePurchaseOrderModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var response = await _iPurchaseOrderService.CreatePurchaseOrder(model);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ResponseMessageModel>();
                if (responseMessage.ResponseMessage == ResponseMessage.PurchaseOrderCreatedSucessfully)
                {
                    TempData["Success"] = ResponseMessage.PurchaseOrderCreatedSucessfully;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "PurchaseOrder");
                }
            }
            TempData["Error"] = $"Something went wrong";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "PurchaseOrder");
        }
        await InitializedViewBagAsync();
        var vendorListResponse = await _iPurchaseOrderService.GetAllVendorList();
        if (vendorListResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var vendorList = await vendorListResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<VendorModel>>();
            var vendorListmodel = new CreatePurchaseOrderModel()
            {
                Vendor = vendorList
            };
            return View(vendorListmodel);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: It think it would be more easy for us to add the js codes to modify the input name when we submit the form rather than modify the logical in jqury(I tried serval times yesterday to modify the codes in jqury repeater but failed, and it would take more time to test if the codes would cause other error),I tried to add the js codes and succeeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error was caused by this code:

```
var matches = $input.attr('name').match(/\[[^\]]+\]/g);

 var name = matches ?
  // strip "[" and "]" characters
 last(matches).replace(/\[|\]/g, '') :
 $input.attr('name');
                        

 var newName = groupName + '[' + index + '].' + name +($input.is(':checkbox') || $input.attr('multiple') ? '[]' : '');

 $input.attr('name', newName);
```

The code reads name from last value inside`[]`,and I logged the values of newName, you could see how it works:

Test1:

[image]

Test2:

[image]

To bind your model,I think it's more convenient if you would add js codes to change the input name when you submit the form rather than modify the logic in jQuery.

I tried as below:

```
<script>
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("product");
    $('#save').click(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            items[i].setAttribute("name", "ProductDetails["+i+"].ProductId")
        }        
    });
</script>
```

......

```
<div data-repeater-list="">
        <div data-repeater-item="">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <input  class="product"name="ProductId" />               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add" />
    <input id="save"type="submit" value="Save" />
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Ruikai Feng It worked
It's means a lot. :)